# Filter parameters by model in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm filtering passwords in my Rails 3.1 app's `config/application.rb` file as usual with:

`config.filter_parameters += [:password]`

However, I'm got an email field in two different models, and I'd like to filter email from only one of those models.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615805/custom-filtering-of-parameters-in-rails-3-using-config-filter-parameters

Comment: Actually, the entire params hash is 'flattened' before passing it to a the `filter_params` lambda, so a these params, `{ "model_1[email]" => "address_1", "model_2[email]" => "address_2" }`, essentially end up looking like this inside the lambda: `{ "email" => "address_1", "email" => "address_2" }`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is really old, but I got here before finding the solution elsewhere. So I'll post an answer in case it helps someone:

In Rails 7, you can do:

```rb
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  self.filter_attributes += [ :email ]
end
```

to filter attributes per model